# laravel blade templating error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I've got a master template at `resources/views/layouts/main.blade.php`. It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
@yield('test')
</body>
</html>
```

I'm stubbing out the login page at `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.main)  

@section('test')
    test
@endsection
```

That's about as simple as it can get-- but I'm seeing the usual meaningless Laravel error messages:

```
FatalErrorException in 180d7ceab6e7cde074091b437eb5346a line 6:
syntax error, unexpected '__data' (T_STRING)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed a quote in this row: `@extends('layouts.main)`

Answer (score 0):

your statement `@extends('layouts.main)` is missing single quot " ' "